# Solution to a href within a href?

Tags: html, css, href

I use CSS tooltips that must be wrapped in a "a href" to work.

```
<a href="#">
<img src="http://www.url.com/image.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" />
<span class="tooltip center white">
<img src=" http://www.url.com/image.png" alt="" width="80" height="80" />iPad [add_to_cart_anchor item="ipad"]purchase the iPad[/add_to_cart_anchor] </span>
</a>
```

As you can see, I'm using "The Tooltip" and Cart66 (use of the anchor shortcode).

It outputs as follows:

```
<a href="#">
<img width="20" height="20" alt="" src="http://www.url.com/image.png"/>
<span class="tooltip center white">
<img width="80" height="80" alt="" src=" http://www.url.com/image.png"/>iPad </span>
</a>
<a href="http://www.url.com/cart?task=add-to-cart-anchor&amp;cart66ItemId=1">purchase the iPad</a>
```

The problem is that the "purchase the iPad" is a href wrapped inside a href in code, thus it is dropped outside of the tooltip. How can I sort this out so the "purchase..." link is still within the span, hence the tooltip, whilst still allowing the tooltip to work? (I've tested without the `<a>` wrap and the tooltip then doesn't work at all.)

Comment: Can I have css tag? So I can create html file and working on that?

Comment: CSS is here: http://pastebin.com/dh4kFbQg (note: you can use the applegreen to replace the white in code above)

Comment: I think the real solution here is not to abuse `<a>` for use with tooltips like this in the first place.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Is there a way around this whilst still using this tooltip, as I have already implemented it site-wide! :/

Comment: Using nested `href` is "illegal" according to the w3c...I *highly* doubt you will be able to hack this into working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:hover` selector for any element, not just anchors:

HTML:

```
<span class="tooltipwrapper">
  ...
</span>
```

So in your CSS you would have:

```
span.tooltipwrapper:hover .tooltip {
  ...
}
```

instead of:

```
a:hover .tooltip {
  ...
}
```

and it should work the same.